# D3.js Force Layout : How to stop initial movement in force layout graph?

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using [Sticky Force Layout](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/3750558). My code with initial tickling can be seen [here](http://embed.plnkr.co/p4tKgduWGdLdao1yfJkw/). I have followed the [Fisheye distortion code](http://bost.ocks.org/mike/fisheye/) that having static layout. But I am not getting the expected output. My code is [here](http://embed.plnkr.co/LGgnYZTOkfCMaMqZL7qj/).

Comment: Do you want a [static force layout](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/1667139)?

Comment: Yes, I have implemented the same here http://embed.plnkr.co/LGgnYZTOkfCMaMqZL7qj/. But its not meet my expectation.

Comment: How does it not meet your expectations?

Comment: When I am assigning co-ordinates of nodes. Its coming into a line. You can see the same in the above mention link.

Comment: I have used the Fisheye distortion code with my input json. It also giving me same output.(all node in a line).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set the cooling parameter `alpha` to 0 or less:

```
var force = d3.layout.force()
                .linkDistance(75)
                .alpha(0)
                .size([width, height])
                .on("tick", tick);
```

And update the `tick` function:

```
function tick() {
 var k = 0;
 while ((force.alpha() > 1e-2) && (k < 150)) {
    force.tick();
    k = k + 1;
 }
 node.attr("transform", function(d) { return "translate(" + d.x + "," + d.y + ")"; });
 }
```

This should 'calm down' the initial movement a lot, but not 100% static.

Comment: Thanks @Fengshuo, I had tried for this tick function but while declaring force layout, I was not using `alpha(0)` that was not working much. But wow its not 100% static but still its very helpful. Thanks again :)